# Rendering drupal login form in a modal window

Tags: users, javascript

I need to display the login form in a modal window when a user clicks a link on my website. I am doing that using jquery ui dialog currently.

However, once the user logs in, i don't want a page refresh instead i just want the modal window to get reloaded with some content.

how do i achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried ctools ? There is an example that does that.

Answer (score 2):

[Modal forms](http://drupal.org/project/modal_forms) module might help you.

> Modal forms make use of the modal feature in the ctools module to open some common forms in a modal window.
>
> **Supported forms:**
>
> - Log in (modal_forms/nojs/login) Request new password
> - (modal_forms/nojs/password) Create new account
> - (modal_forms/nojs/register) Contact (modal_forms/nojs/contact)
> - Comment (modal_forms/%ctools_js/comment/reply/%node) Webform
>   (modal_forms/%ctools_js/webform/%node)

Answer (score 0):

Use Lightbox module and mention rel in the url tag like below i mentioned

```
<a href="search.php" rel='lightframe'>Search</a>
```

you can see a live example in my site www.richtown.ae(click Mortage Calculator in bottom)

or you can use popup module to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The [Colorbox Module](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox) provides this functionallity.